# App loading forever - firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have a simple component that checks if the user is logged in or not.

20% of the times this works correctly, but the other 80%, the page is just loading forever as firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged is never fired or it is fired after minutes of loading.

What could be happening?

```html
class Loading extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkIfLoggedIn();
  }

  checkIfLoggedIn = () => {
    console.warn("checking if logged in")
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(
      user => {
        console.warn('AUTH STATE CHANGED CALLED ', user)
        if (user) {
          console.log("there is indeed a user")

          this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
        } else {
          console.log("go authenticate")
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
        }
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Please wait there</Text>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: are you using the @react-native-firebase/auth

Comment: There could be a network problem

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was navigating to an unexisting component.